# Consecutive constants in Java used to identify networking messages

Tags: java, networking, constants

I have a Java problem here. I have many constants, which are consecutive constant integers, currently defined like:

```
interface Flags {
  static final short A = 0;
  static final short B = A + 1;
  static final short FIRST_USER_FLAG = B + 1;
}
```

Many of you would now recommend me to use Enum. The problem is, I need more than one place with those flags. So it would be like:

```
interface CustomFlags {
  static final short USER_A = Flags.FIRST_USER_FLAG + 1;
  static final short USER_B = USER_A + 1;
}
```

The code you see here, also has to be the same on two sides of network, included in server code and client code. Every message between those has defined it's flag and by this flag, the networking creates message object, registered with this flag. This doesn't seem to be the best approach, but I couldn't think of anything better. And the problem is, that the networking code has its own flags and messages, which does some basic authentication and handshaking. And then there has to be messages (and their flags) defined by the code that uses the networking.

My question is, how to make this more maintainable and readable? Also, if there's anyone, who knows about better approach to send and recreate messages (I'm using both TCP and UDP, depends on the message), I would be really thankful to hear it.

If there's something I didn't explain, please let me know and I'll add it.

PS: Sorry for my bad english, as I'm not native speaker.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are these "flags" message IDs? I.e. are these ids used for routing the messages?

Comment: Yes. In my code, I do `connection.registerMessage(short flag, Class<? extends Message> msgClass, IMessageHandler handler)` and everytime, message with this flag is read by that connection, it creates the Message and gives it stream to parse data from. Then it notified the handler and gives it the message object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave it the way it is. That's quite a usual technique for defining constants of a protocol. If the peer isn't Java I would probably 'de-engineer' a bit further, and just define the names and their values directly without worrying about the arithmetic. You don't want this to be easy to change, you actually want it to be impossible to change, so that inadvertent protocol incompatibilities don't creep in. Enums are for cases where you are more interested in the names and in type safety and not too concerned about the actual values, ordinals, etc.

Comment: Currently both in java. Later it will probably have client in Objective-C or C++. The problem is, that I need to map those flags to their message objects. Every message has method `short getFlag()` that is used to identify the message when I'm sending it. The connection then writes the short into the TCP stream (or byte array if using UDP). But as I said, it seems unmaintainable when there will be even more messages and their flags.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't need to be maintainable: it needs to be the same at both ends. As you are going to have Objective-C clients what you need is a definition that looks as similar as possible in both languages.

Comment: I'll probably then go with this:
`interface Flags {
  short FLAG_1 = -32768;
  short FLAG_2 = -32767;
}` and so on. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Enums are still the answer. You could specifically list a value, or put the enums in an interface document common to both the server and the client, or you could simply require that the value be the same across the various areas. IE,

```
public enum Flags
{
  short A (0);
  short B (1);
  short FIRST_USER_FLAG (2);
  private int value;

  private Flags(int value) {
      this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Then specify that the enum must meet that criteria on both server and client. You could provide the enum if desired to the server.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't simply set values for enums (got to use the A(0), B(1) etc.). The problem with this is, that it's still not easily maintainable. If I'll use something like my code, and define static integer and then I'll increment it every message, wouldn't that be better?

Comment: @DeToX: Corrected my answer, it was a bit more complex than I thought, but it should work.